# Issue Implementing Custom Gradient Descent Function

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am implementing my own/custom Gradient descent algorithm using python but the weights and biases that are returned by my algorithm has 10 values (shape=(10, )) but my input data has only 1 column so I am expecting it to return **1 Weight and 1 Bias**

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def SGD(X, y, learning_rate=0.01, max_iter=1000):
    w = np.random.randn(X.shape[1])
    b = np.random.randn(1,)
    print(w, b)
    n = len(X)
    loss_list = []

    for i in range(max_iter):
        y_pred = w*X + b

        Lw = -(2/n)*sum(X*(y - y_pred))
        Lb = -(2/n)*sum(y - y_pred)
        w = w - learning_rate*Lw
        b = b - learning_rate*Lb

        loss = np.square(np.subtract(y, y_pred)).mean()
        loss_list.append(loss)

        print(f"Epoch: {i}, loss: {loss}")

    return w, b

x = list(range(1, 11))
y = []
for i in x:
    y.append(i**2)

x, y = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1), np.array(y)
w, b = SGD(x, y)

print("\n\n\n\n")
print(w)
print(b)
```

Loss of last iteration:

```
Epoch: 999, loss: 0.11521764208740602
```

Returned weight and bias respectively,

```
w: [0.00149535 0.00777379 0.01823786 0.03288755 0.05172286 0.07474381
 0.10195038 0.13334257 0.1689204  0.20868384] # giving 10 values

b: [ 0.98958964  3.94588026  8.87303129 15.77104274 24.63991461 35.47964689
 48.29023958 63.07169269 79.82400621 98.54718014] # giving 10 values
```

I am not understanding the cause, how this is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your `y` is a 1d row list, but `y_pred` is a `1xn` column list, so subtracting them will give you an `nxn` matrix which you don't want. The fix is to just reshape `y` before you call your function like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def SGD(X, y, learning_rate=0.01, max_iter=1000):
    w = np.random.randn(X.shape[1])
    b = np.random.randn(1,)
    print(w, b)
    n = len(X)
    loss_list = []

    for i in range(max_iter):
        y_pred = w*X + b

        Lw = -(2/n)*sum(X*(y - y_pred))
        Lb = -(2/n)*sum(y - y_pred)
        w = w - learning_rate*Lw
        b = b - learning_rate*Lb

        loss = np.square(np.subtract(y, y_pred)).mean()
        loss_list.append(loss)

        print(f"Epoch: {i}, loss: {loss}")

    return w, b

x = list(range(1, 11))
y = []
for i in x:
    y.append(i**2)

x, y = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1), np.array(y).reshape((-1, 1)) # Change is here
w, b = SGD(x, y)

print("\n\n\n\n")
print(w)
print(b)
```

and then `w, b` are:

```
[10.94655101]
[-21.6278976]
```

respectively